# Destructuring in ES6 syntax of of req.body gives me the whole object instead of specific value

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

it's probably a lack of understanding but this is the first time this is happening. My function looks like this:

```js
exports.handleFormSubmit = functions.https.onRequest(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    const { formData} = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log(formData.name); // gives the name
   
    // if I do this instead

    const { formData: name } = JSON.parse(req.body); 
    console.log(name) // gives entire object instead of just the name.
})
```

What is causing the behaviour described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{formData}` expands to `{formData: formData}` ([see here](https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/)). This means that the value at key `formData` will be stored into the variable `formData`. When you have `{formData: name}`, it means that the value at key `formData` will be stored into the variable `name`, which is essentially equivalent to what you have before. If you want to destructure `name`, then you should double destructure:

```js
const {formData: {name}} = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

Comment: Minor nit: *"This means that the key `formData` will be stored into the variable `formData`."* Not the key, the *value* of the property the key identifies.